# Puppeteer sharp --no-sandbox option seems to not work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: .net-core, puppeteer, ubuntu-20.04, puppeteer-sharp

I use an Azure VM on ubuntu 20.04. I would like to set up puppeteer sharp on this VM to use it with my dotnet core API.

But, I awlays have this error :

> Failed to launch browser! [0408/085321.321602:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(100)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

If I run "sudo chromium", I have this error :

> zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(100)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

If I run "sudo chromium --no-sandbox", I have some error messages but, chromium is launched.

In my dotnet core API, I wrote :

```
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync();


var launchOptions = new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
    ExecutablePath = "/snap/bin/chromium",
    Args = new[] { "--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox" },
};


var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(launchOptions);

_logger.LogError(launchOptions.ToString());

var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

await page.SetContentAsync(htmlContent);
```

I got this error :

> Failed to launch browser! [0408/085321.321602:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(100)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

I don't understand why as I correctly passed "--no-sandbox" argument to LaunchAsync method. When you read my manual tests, It seems that --no-sandbox is ignored.

Comment: Did you check [this issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3698)?